# How to prepend specific class at run time?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to use `prepend` for instantiated classes at run time?
Like for example, I need prepend specific class based of value of passed params to initialize method..

ex (if prepend is allowed to be called in initialize) :

```
def initialize(param)
    prepend TestB if param == 2
    prepend TestC if param == 3
end
```

but of course, this will lead into error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `prepend' for .. etc
```

How would I achieve this? I need to override some methods in a clean way, while instantiating the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend) is a method belonging to `Module`, so it cannot be invoked on instances of a class (which is where you are inside the `initialize` method). If you want to, you could use [`extend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Object.html#method-i-extend) (a method belonging to `Object`) to mix in different method implementations into the instance of your class.

Personally I would consider this to be a kind of [Control Couple](https://github.com/troessner/reek/blob/master/docs/Control-Couple.md) and rather try and avoid it. Depending on your concrete situation, a factory or adapter pattern might be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, my situation here does not allow me to implement  factory or adapter pattern

Comment: I presume you are referring to changing `prepend TestB if param == 2` to `extend TestB if param == 2`. As you say, this would cause `c = C.new` (`C` being the class) to make the instance methods of `TestB` methods defined on `c.singleton_class`, are therefore only available to that instance. What needs to be said, I think, is that every instance of `C` would have the instance methods of `Type` in its singleton class, which raises the question: "How could that be preferable to simply `C.include TestB`?".